# rgl package with rsconnect package

Tags: r, rgl

I encounter some problem when using the rgl package to plot a 3D picture on shinyR. My code works without error or problem on the local Rstudio. The 3D plot does really show up just as I expected. However, whenever I publish it to shinyapps.io through rsconnect package, the 3D plot does not show up on the website. Simultaneously, no error occurs. This confuses me a lot. I look for the solution on the internet and upload a simple example to test. Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)
library(rglwidget)
options(rgl.useNULL=TRUE) 
open3d(useNULL = TRUE) 
ids <- plot3d(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), rnorm(100))[1] 
scene <- scene3d() 
rgl.close() 
ui <- (fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("chk", label = "Display", value = FALSE),
  rglwidgetOutput("wdg")
))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)
  save <- options(rgl.inShiny = TRUE)
  on.exit(options(save))
  output$wdg <- renderRglwidget({
    rglwidget(scene)
  })
}
if (interactive())
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Finally, there is error message:

> Warning in rgl.init(initValue, onlyNULL) :
>   
>   RGL: unable to open X11 display
>   
> Warning: 'rgl_init' failed, running with rgl.useNULL = TRUE
>   
> The functions in the rglwidget package have been moved to rgl.
>   
> Attaching package: ‘rglwidget’
>   
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:rgl’:
>   
>     playwidget, rglwidget
>   
> Error in value[3L] : app.R did not return a shiny.appobj object.
>   
> Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne ->

As you can see, the error message mentions “X11”, I google this only to find all these X11 problems are related to ubanto or mac environment (mine is win10 ). Therefore, I couldn’t find useful answer. I have also tried the capabilities() function but the result just says my X11 is False. I could not figure out which part went wrong and hence I list all my information.

Great thanks if anyone can help or provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the `rglwidget` package; it is obsolete.

The warnings about X11 are coming because you're trying to set up a local window on the Shiny server.  To avoid doing that, use `options(rgl.useNULL = TRUE)` *before* `library(rgl)`.  If you do this, it won't be necessary in the `open3d` call.